# Does `ip link` em1 = p4p1?

Tags: networking, ethernet, ip

I'm trying to remotely manage a Dell server with Ubuntu 14.04. The server has has a 540-BBW Broadcom 5720 QP 1Gb Network Daughter Card. Broadcom [docs](https://www.broadcom.com/collateral/pb/2CS95720-PB04-R.pdf)  say it has two PCIe slots with two ethernet ports a piece.

I read through these [biosdevname](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming_Using_biosdevname.html#tabl-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming_biosdevname) docs and shows `p<slot>p<ethernet port>`. `ip link` shows p4p1, p4p2, p6p1, & p6p2. That makes sense. The card must be using slots 4 & 6.

What doesn't make sense to me is `ip link` also shows em1, em2, em3, em4. These are described as embedded network interfaces. Are these not aliases for the above PCIe ethernet ports? If they are aliases, how do I know which one corresponds to the other? In-other-words, does em1 correspond to the same hardware port as p4p1?

```
cameron@echo:~$ ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: em1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:a8:42:2b:4c:39 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: em2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:a8:42:2b:4c:3a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: em3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:a8:42:2b:4c:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: em4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 44:a8:42:2b:4c:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: p4p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:12:11:e8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
7: p4p2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a0:36:9f:12:11:ea brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: p6p1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:07:43:33:51:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: p6p2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:07:43:33:51:08 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
10: lxcbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 1e:c4:f7:44:50:cd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:f4:3d:2c:be brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Update 1. Here is the PCI info if this helps. May be I was wrong about the hardware. It would be great to know which link above corresponds to which of these PCI devices.

```
cameron@echo:~$ lspci -nn | grep Ethernet
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:165f]
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Chelsio Communications Inc T520-CR Unified Wire Ethernet Controller [1425:5001]
04:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Chelsio Communications Inc T520-CR Unified Wire Ethernet Controller [1425:5001]
04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Chelsio Communications Inc T520-CR Unified Wire Ethernet Controller [1425:5001]
04:00.3 Ethernet controller [0200]: Chelsio Communications Inc T520-CR Unified Wire Ethernet Controller [1425:5001]
04:00.4 Ethernet controller [0200]: Chelsio Communications Inc T520-CR Unified Wire Ethernet Controller [1425:5401]
82:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 [8086:1528] (rev 01)
82:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2 [8086:1528] (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, there are three separate network interfaces. From [these docs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-network-cards-command/), I learned that `sudo lshw -class network` can be used to see which logical names are associated with each pci address.

```
*-network:0
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: em1
       version: 00
       serial: 44:a8:42:2b:4c:39
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm vpd msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.137 duplex=full firmware=FFV7.10.61 bc 5720-v1.36 ip=10.1.14.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:89 memory:93330000-9333ffff memory:93340000-9334ffff memory:93350000-9335ffff memory:93700000-9373ffff

  *-network:0 DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller 10-Gigabit X540-AT2
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:82:00.0
       logical name: p4p1
       version: 01
       serial: a0:36:9f:12:11:e8
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ixgbe driverversion=4.2.1-k firmware=0x80000389 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:90 memory:c8200000-c83fffff memory:c8404000-c8407fff memory:c8600000-c867ffff memory:c8700000-c87fffff memory:c8800000-c88fffff
```